# How to create multiple barcodes in java using barbecue library?

Tags: java, netbeans, barcode

I want to generate multiple barcodes in java using java.
The scenario looks like this:

**I have a textfield named copies, I want to generate barcodes using the barbecue library and based on the number given,**
uy
So, if I input 3 in the textfield, it will generate 3 barcodes with a number incremented. And the number will increment  (e.g, 1, 2,3) for three barcodes.

Can anyone help me? your help is much highly appreciated

Here's my code in producing the single barcode:

```
new File("C:\\Generated Barcodes").mkdir();
       new File("D:\\Back-Up Generated Barcodes").mkdir();

    //Get 128B Barcode instance from the Factory
    Barcode barcode = null;

        try {
            barcode = BarcodeFactory.createCode128B(res.getText());

        } catch (BarcodeException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Barcode_IT.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    barcode.setBarHeight(40);
    barcode.setBarWidth(2);

           generate2.setEnabled(false);
             save.setEnabled(true);
             Edit.setEnabled(true);


             File imgFile = new File("C://Generated Barcodes//"+res2.getText()+"_"+res.getText()+".png");

        try {
            //Write the bar code to PNG file
            BarcodeImageHandler.savePNG(barcode, imgFile);
        } catch (OutputException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Barcode_IT.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
              ImageIcon imgThisImg = new ImageIcon("C://Generated Barcodes//"+res2.getText()+"_"+res.getText()+".png");
            lres.setIcon(imgThisImg);
            file.setText(res2.getText()+"_"+res.getText()+".png");


    }

        }catch(Exception e){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Jframe, "Something Went Wrong!",
        "Inane warning", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

         }
```

Comment: what is your problem generating bar-code  or incrementing numbers?see this one http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/barcodes/barbecue/barcode-size.html

Comment: sir, I already tried that one, and it did work however, what I would like to happen is that, I want to generate multiple barcodes based on the number of copies given.

Comment: It's working sir, however, I want to generate multiple barcodes instead of producing one barcode

Comment: yes post it ....if u put 5 in the textfiled what is ur expected output?

Comment: I've edited my post with the code on how I produce the single barcode

Comment: If I put 5 in text filed as the number of copies and 1 in ID_textfield, I would expect that it will produce 5 barcode with unique numbers that's being incremented (e.g., 1,2,3,4,5).

Answer (score 0):

do you know for loop?use a loop to generate multiple bar codes .
like this

```
//Get 128B Barcode instance from the Factory
        Barcode barcode = null;
        int code = Integer.parseInt(res.getText());

        for (int i = 1; i <= code; i++) {
            try {
                barcode = BarcodeFactory.createCode128B(i + "");
            } catch (BarcodeException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            barcode.setBarHeight(40);
            barcode.setBarWidth(2);

            File imgFile = new File("C://Generated Barcodes//" + res2.getText() + "_" + i + ".png");
            System.out.println(code);

            try {
                //Write the bar code to PNG file
                BarcodeImageHandler.savePNG(barcode, imgFile);
            } catch (OutputException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            ImageIcon imgThisImg = new ImageIcon("C://Generated Barcodes//" + res2.getText() + "_" + i + ".png");
            lres.setIcon(imgThisImg);
        }
```

Comment: by the way sir, how to display it?

Comment: @Newbieu should think it.u have multiple images and u have one lable .in  this code it will generate a image then set it to lable.this will happens multiple times u  only see  last image but they have saved as png

Comment: sit, actually it did not work for me...? what happened with this one sir?

Comment: what this does is save images as u want